# Return integer in function String

Tags: java

How return integer in function String

It's my code

```
public class Utils {
    public static String type(String s){
        if(UraniumProtectMain.materialname){
            return s;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(s); //<--- It's
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your code?  This is not clear right now.

Comment: The method in Java can't return either String or int - you should use only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to return both Integer and String, you can use return type as Object class,  because Object is super class of all classes and we can hold any type of value in Object variable.

```
public static Object type(String s){    
    // code here
}
```

Now you can get the type of value return by type with the help of instanceOf method

```
if(Utils.type() instaceOf String)
{
    // code here
} else if(Utils.type() instanceOf Integer) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: you'd better explain why he has to do that

Comment: he want to return both Integer and String this can be accomplished with help of Object class, as you know Object variable can hold any type of value. And he can easily get the type with the help of instanceOf method

Comment: great, I wrote that because your answer flagged as a low quality answer, here in SO, you are always required to explain your answer, like what you did in the comment to me but you have to do that in the answer itself to avoid being flagged as a low quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either return Object or return integer as String.

Answer (score 0):

As [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689942/user3689942) has suggested that you can return change method return type to object. But, apart from that you can also use either of

1. String.valueOf(number) (my preference)
2. Integer.toString(number)

to return integer as string and perform type check at method calling point